# Getting Error While Post Data Using AFnetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

This is my Code:

```
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dictionary options:0 error:nil];
    NSString *json = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSDictionary *dict = @{@"body":json};
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [manager POST:@"http://abc/" parameters:dict success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSString *myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.request.HTTPBody encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", myString);
    }];
```

But i am Getting Error Like This
    `body=%7B%22pincode%22%3A%22gfgfgf%22%2C%22mobile%22%3A%221111%22%2C%22password%22%3A%22rwerew%22%2C%22profile_pic%22%3A%22%22%2C%22social_accesstoken%22%3A%22%22%2C%22sponsor_choice%22%3A3%2C%22sponsor_id%22%3A%22%22%2C%22social_provider%22%3A%22Normal%22%2C%22email%22%3A%22ghffh%22%2C%22gender%22%3A1%2C%22name%22%3A%22narendra%22%2C%22nickname%22%3A1233%2C%22country%22%3A%22Japan%20%28JPY%29%22%2C%22fromLogin%22%3A%22%22%2C%22methodName%22%3A%22signup%22%2C%22birth_date%22%3A%2208-06-01%22%7D`

Can any one suggest me on this kind...

Comment: why you are converting error to encoded string ... first just print error message like `NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);`  ... and post that error

Comment: can you show some sample which type of parameter you need to pass

Comment: Please update your code with requested parameters.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to convert error to encoded string....

First of all clear that.. which type of parameter you needed..

and then try this code for simple posting data:

(Make related changes according to your parameters needed)

```
    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];


NSDictionary *param = @ {@"body":json};


[manager POST:URL_HERE parameters:param
success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
{
    NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
}
failure:
 ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
 }];
```

Comment: check this line `NSDictionary *dict = @{@"body":son};` and ask to questioner related to which type of parameter needed, then customize your answer